# Why is Firefox opening links in Chrome?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, kde

Over the past few weeks Chrome tabs have been freezing quite a bit, so I've decided to switch to firefox. I have made Firefox the default browser in every way I am aware (KDE's "Web Browser" default application, KDE's HTML file association, and the x-www-browser alternative) and every app now seems to be opening links in Firefox. Every app EXCEPT Firefox which continues to open links in Chrome.

I have made a video of this happening (as well as showing that it's set as default): https://youtu.be/Wa0cSxrulnE

I missed these in the video:

```
starkrg@Moya:~$ xdg-mime query default text/html
firefox.desktop
starkrg@Moya:~$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
firefox.desktop
starkrg@Moya:~$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
firefox.desktop
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which links? `mailto:` ones?

Comment: No, http and https links, like the ones shown in the video. I found the problem and am creating an answer so other people know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

After several days, and shortly after making this post, I finally found the solution.

1. In the address bar enter "about:config".
2. Acknowledge that these are potentially dangerous settings (at your own risk).
3. Search for "network.protocol-handler.external.shell" set it to "true"

I do not know why this is necessary. I assume what it does is force Firefox to check with the OS to find out who is supposed to handle http and https links, discovers that it is, and then loads them. I don't know if this increases the time it takes for links to load or if that's just how Firefox is.